# How to find the user's location in swift?

Tags: swift, location, cllocation

Hello I am developing an application for ios and one of it's functions  has to find the user's current location. Here is my code:

```
 import UIKit
 import MapKit
 import CoreLocation
 import SwiftyJSON

 struct City {
let name : String
let location : CLLocation
let description :String
let imageName : String

func distanceTo(location:CLLocation) -> Int
{
    let distanceMeters = location.distanceFromLocation(self.location)
    let distanceKilometers = distanceMeters / 1000.00
    return Int(round(100 * distanceKilometers) / 100)
}
}

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var LabelTest: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var Slider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var LabelValueSlider: UILabel!
var MySliderCurrentValue = Double()

var manager = CLLocationManager()

var userLoc: CLLocationCoordinate2D!


{
    willSet{
        self.orderCitysByProximity()
        self.filterCitysByProximity(Int(self.Slider.value))
        self.LocateMe(manager)

    }
}
var cities = [City]()
var nearbyCities = [City]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let path: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("cities", ofType: "json") as String!
    let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path) as NSData!
    //let ReadableJSON = JSON ( data:jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil )

    do {
        let jsonObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! [String:AnyObject]
        for city in jsonObject["cities"] as! [[String:AnyObject]] {
            //let coordinates = position["Position"] as! [String:CLLocationDegrees]
            let cityName = city["Name"] as! String
            let latitude = city["Latitude"] as! Double
            let longitude = city["Longitude"] as! Double
            let description = city["Description"] as! String
            let image = city["Image"] as! String
            let location = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
            let city = City(name: cityName, location: location,description: description, imageName: image)
            cities.append(city)
            // print(cities)
        }


        self.orderCitysByProximity()
       self.filterCitysByProximity(Int(self.Slider.value))


    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func SliderChange(sender: UISlider) {
    let MySliderCurrentValue: String = String(Int(sender.value))
    LabelValueSlider.text = MySliderCurrentValue
    self.filterCitysByProximity(Int(sender.value))
}

@IBAction func goToTableView()
{
   if let tableViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tableViewController") as? TableViewController
   {
        tableViewController.cities = self.nearbyCities
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tableViewController, animated: true)
    }
}


func filterCitysByProximity(kilometers:Int)
{
    self.nearbyCities.removeAll()
    for city in self.cities {
        if(city.distanceTo(self.userLoc) <= kilometers*2)
        {
            self.nearbyCities.append(city)
        }
    }

    self.LabelTest.text = "you have \(self.nearbyCities.count) cities nearby"
   let OrderedArray = self.nearbyCities.sort({ $0.distanceTo(self.userLoc) < $1.distanceTo(self.userLoc) })
   self.nearbyCities = OrderedArray
}

func orderCitysByProximity()
{
    let OrderedArray = self.cities.sort({ $0.distanceTo(self.userLoc) < $1.distanceTo(self.userLoc) })
    self.cities = OrderedArray
}

@IBAction func LocateMe(sender: AnyObject) {
    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()

}
func  locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let userlocation: CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation
    manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: userlocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userlocation.coordinate.longitude)
    self.userLoc = location



}
}
```

On the bottom you will see the func locationManager, where I am trying to find the user's current location. Would you please advise me how to start this function so that the app recognise when I type userLoc. userLoc are the coordinations of the user and I have to use them in other functions like func filterCitysByProximity, and the rest, which you can see in the code.

Comment: What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Reason of your problem :-

When you call the delegate of the **CLLocationManager** in `viewDidLoad()` it takes some time to retrieve the usersCurrent Location , but even before usersLocation could relay back to you, your functions requiring usersCurrent Location were being triggered as you had called them in `viewDidLoad()` thus causing the error!

your Code should look like this:-

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
import SwiftyJSON

struct City {
let name : String
let location : CLLocation
let description :String
let imageName : String

func distanceTo(location:CLLocation) -> Int
{
    let distanceMeters = location.distanceFromLocation(self.location)
    let distanceKilometers = distanceMeters / 1000.00
    return Int(round(100 * distanceKilometers) / 100)
}
}

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var LabelTest: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var Slider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var LabelValueSlider: UILabel!
var MySliderCurrentValue = Double()

var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

var userLoc : CLLocation!
var cities = [City]()
var nearbyCities = [City]()



override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()



    let path: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("cities", ofType: "json") as String!
    let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path) as NSData!
    do {
        let jsonObject = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! [String:AnyObject]
        for city in jsonObject["cities"] as! [[String:AnyObject]] {
            //let coordinates = position["Position"] as! [String:CLLocationDegrees]
            let cityName = city["Name"] as! String
            let latitude = city["Latitude"] as! Double
            let longitude = city["Longitude"] as! Double
            let description = city["Description"] as! String
            let image = city["Image"] as! String
            let location = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
            let city = City(name: cityName, location: location,description: description, imageName: image)
            cities.append(city)

        }

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }


    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

            if locationManager.respondsToSelector(#selector(locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization)) {
                locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
                locationManager.requestLocation()
            }
            else {
                locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            }


}


@IBAction func SliderChange(sender: UISlider) {
    let MySliderCurrentValue: String = String(Int(sender.value))
    LabelValueSlider.text = MySliderCurrentValue
    if userLoc != nil{
       self.filterCitysByProximity(Int(sender.value), location: userLoc)
    }else{
        let alertC : UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Iwin", message: "UserLocation Not Updated wait a while", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let okAction : UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "oK", style: .Default, handler: { (okActn) in
            print("User pressed ok")
        })
        alertC.addAction(okAction)
        alertC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = view
        alertC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = view.frame
        self.presentViewController(alertC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}


//Segue to .. :-


@IBAction func goToTableView()
{
   if let tableViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tableViewController") as? TableViewController
   {
        tableViewController.cities = self.nearbyCities
        print(nearbyCities)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tableViewController, animated: true)
    }
}

     @IBAction func LocateMe(sender: AnyObject) {

}





//Class Functions call :-





func filterCitysByProximity(kilometers:Int, location: CLLocation)
{
    self.nearbyCities.removeAll()
    for city in self.cities {
        if(city.distanceTo(location) <= kilometers*2)
        {
            self.nearbyCities.append(city)
        }
    }

    self.LabelTest.text = "you have \(self.nearbyCities.count) cities nearby"
    let OrderedArray = self.nearbyCities.sort({ $0.distanceTo(location) < $1.distanceTo(location) })
    self.nearbyCities = OrderedArray
}

func orderCitysByProximity(location: CLLocation)
{
    let OrderedArray = self.cities.sort({ $0.distanceTo(location) < $1.distanceTo(location) })
    self.cities = OrderedArray
}




//Location Manager Functions :-



func  locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    userLoc = locations[0] as CLLocation
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    print(userLoc)
    self.orderCitysByProximity(userLoc)
    self.filterCitysByProximity(Int(self.Slider.value), location : userLoc)

}


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

    if status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {

        print("authorised call came . . . . ")
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError){


print(error.localizedDescription)
locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}


}
```

Add `privacy - location usage description` : `Result` to your info.plist
Also if your **didUpdateLocations** function doesn't get called

- reset your location Services by going into settings->General->Reset
- Try google, you will find multiple questions

Comment: Readdy I sent it to you

Comment: I got it to working , but i couldnt understand a single thing that you were trying to do here... look at my code

Comment: I have sent you please check it, thank you very much!!

Comment: Hey Would you send me the new fie per email, because I have made some changes and now I can't integrate it here. It would be awesome thanks!

Comment: No problem I am trying to implement it now, I think it will work fine

Comment: Accept and +1  this as answer in it helped :)